# Recovery HD present but can't boot from it

Tags: macos, partition, recovery

I fiddled with partitions on my MacBook Pro with OS X Yosemite, but now I'd like to reinstall the OS to restore original setup.  Recovery HD is there, but if I press CMD + R at boot, Internet Recovery is run instead of normal Recovery from Recovery HD.  I know that I can reinstall OS also from the Internet, but it would take forever and I need to restore my Macbook within two days (downloading OS X Yosemite from App Store requires other 3 days and counting right now).

Probably I messed up GUID Partition Table (but OS X works flawless). Is there a way to make it possible to boot from Recovery HD and reinstall OS from there instead of using Internet Recovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recovery HD still has to download OS X from the Internet. Your only hope of not downloading at all is if you have access to some device, either yours or a friend, that already has the OS X installer app. If you do, you should make an 8GB partition on your HD named Untitled and follow [this](http://www.macworld.com/article/2367748/how-to-make-a-bootable-os-x-10-10-yosemite-install-drive.html) procedure to make it a version of Recovery HD that has the OS saved locally.

If you don't have any way to get the OS X installer, the only other thing you could do is wipe your hard drive and restore from a Time Machine backup, using Internet Recovery to facilitate the process.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks.  I'll wait for other possible answers before accepting this one.